# RxJs Subject: Get the emitter

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am working with Subjects and there is a `.subscribe()` in a class. From different other classes I emit values to this class. The problem is that the subscribe is now triggered multiple times and I don't know from where the emits come from.

Is there a way to get the class or reference from where the emit (`.next<T>`) was triggered?

**Desired behaviour:**

In service svc:

```
obs: Subject<Date> = new Subject<Date>();
```

Class 1:

```
svc.obs.next(new Date());
```

Class n:

```
svc.obs.next(new Date());
```

Subscriber:

```
svc.obs.subscribe((date) => {
        console.log("Triggered from: " + svc.obs.getSource().classname); // Desired output: "Triggered from: SomeNamespace.Classname"
});
```

Comment: Can you please show us the `console.log` messages inside `subscribe` and also the instances in the code where you call `obs.next(new Date())`?

Comment: the `.getSource()` cannot output anything because this function does not exist. It is only to demonstrate what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry. I seem to have misunderstood the question. Providing an answer shortly.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `obs: Subject<Date> = new Subject<Date>();` 
by `obs: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();`

Then you can emit the source yourself

```
svc.obs.next({ date: new Date(), source: 'whatever source' });
```

Finally on subscribe:

```
svc.obs.subscribe((data) => {
        console.log("Triggered from: " + data.source + "Date is : "+data.date);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A clean solution to this problem would be to do this.

Inside your service.

```
// First, declare an interface like so.
interface ReactiveDate {
    date: Date,
    type: String
}

// Instantiate the Subject using this interface as the generic type.
obs: Subject<ReactiveDate> = new Subject<ReactiveDate>();
```

Inside your classes.

```
// From Class 1.
svc.obs.next({ date: new Date(), type: 'Class 1' });

// From Class 2.
svc.obs.next({ date: new Date(), type: 'Class 2' });
```

Then, again inside your service.

```
// Apply correct logic on "type" inside the subscribe callback.
obs.subscribe(({ date, type }) => {
        console.log("Triggered from: " + type);
});
```

The "type" is therefore of your own choosing and will be very robust and error-free since you'll always know the values beforehand. You won't be hacking your way through.